# Exporting to excel with cell column width on ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to set column width in the excel for certain columns?

I tried the following but not working.

```
  this.gridOptions.excelStyles = this.excelStyles;
  let params = {
    fileName: 'DelegateStatus',
    sheetName: 'Delegate Status',
    columnWidth: 10        
  }
  this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel(params);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your approach using `columnWidth` is correct however,

`columnWidth` was introduced in version 22.1.0

> AG-1486   [Feature Request]   22.1.0  Allow configuring row groups/cells
>   when exporting to excel/csv

What is the ag-grid version you are using?